# Catch block isn't catching the error thrown in my custom react hook

Tags: react-native, error-handling, async-await, react-hooks

I have an app that uses the user's location. Using Expo's location library, this is how my code is structured.

In the main screen I create a callback function and wrap in in the useCallback HOC.

```
const userLocationCallback = useCallback(async (location) => {
    // if we don't have any locations....fetch them and then sort them
    if (!businessLocations || businessLocations.length <= 0) {
        // todo check for wifi connectivity or data
        let fetchedLocations = await fetchAllLocations();
        sortByClosestLocation(location, fetchedLocations, updateLocations)
        if (fetchedLocations.length >= 5) {
            setListOfClosest(getFirstFromList(5, businessLocations))
        }
    } else {
        sortByClosestLocation(location, businessLocations, updateLocations)
        if (businessLocations.length >= 5) {
            setListOfClosest(getFirstFromList(5, businessLocations))
        }
    }
}, [businessLocations, locationServicesOn, permissionGranted]);
```

This code gets called with the user's location every time it updates. The only part of this code that really matters is the call to **await fetchAllLocations**. This is an api call to a server that gets back JSON.

Here is the custom hook's code:

```
export default (
    shouldTrackLocation,
    timeBetweenUpdates,
    callback,
    locationServicesOn,
    permissionGranted) => {

    const [locationError, setLocationError] = useState(null);

    let time = 0;

    useEffect(() => {

        let subscriber;
        const startWatching = async () => {
            try {
                subscriber = await watchPositionAsync({
                        accuracy: Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
                        // timeInterval and distanceInterval seem to have no effect, but you must have distanceInterval === 0
                        timeInterval: 10000,
                        distanceInterval: 0
                    }, (location) => {
                        if (time === 0 || new Date().getTime() >= time + timeBetweenUpdates) {

                            callback(location).catch(e => {
                                console.log("Location Error: ", "caught the error here")
                                throw e;
                            });
                            time = new Date().getTime();
                        }
                    }
                );
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("Location Error: ", "caught error in catch block")
                setLocationError(e);
            }
        };

        if (shouldTrackLocation && locationServicesOn && permissionGranted) {
            startWatching().catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                subscriber?.remove();
                subscriber = null
            })
        } else {
            subscriber?.remove();
            subscriber = null;
        }

        return () => {
            subscriber?.remove();
        }
    }, [shouldTrackLocation, callback, locationServicesOn, permissionGranted]);

    return [locationError];
}
```

I define a function `startWatching` that uses expo-location's function `watchPositionAsync`. The part of the code that is relevant here is the callback function (second argument passed to watchPositionAsync). The callback function is the code I showed up top - the one I wrapped in useCallback. From the main screen (where this callback function is defined) I call the hook like this:

```
const [locationError] = useCurrentLocation(
        screenIsFocused,
        3000,
        userLocationCallback,
        locationServicesOn,
        permissionGranted,
    );
```

---

Here is the problem. If the callback function generates an error I want to catch it. I'm making an api call, however, if the server is down and the callback throws an error as a result of it being down, then why is it not showing up in the catch block of the startWatching function?

As you can see, I tried catching it immediately by appending .catch(e => ....) to the end of the call. That works, but then when I throw the error inside that block it never hits the catch block below where I'm trying to call `setLocationError(e)`.

I can't seem to understand the flow of my error. I want to do something if the app can't connect to the server. Help me to understand why the catch block is being skipped.

Comment: So, you are basically asking how you can handle errors that may occur at your server-side in case of a network error or something?

Comment: No, I'm trying to handle the error on the client. In the event that the server is down, the api call to get data will fail because the client won't be able to connect to the server. I am able to catch the error when this happens if I add callback(location).catch(e => console.log(e)) inside the startWatching function I created. But that error never gets propagated to the subsequent catch block.

Comment: Ok, same thing. I will add an answer for your case

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, you can modify your custom like like below:

```
  export default (
        shouldTrackLocation,
        timeBetweenUpdates,
        callback,
        locationServicesOn,
        permissionGranted) => {
    
        const [locationError, setLocationError] = useState(null);
    
        let time = 0;
    
        const innerLocationCallback = useCallback(async (location) => {       
            try {
                if (time === 0 || new Date().getTime() >= time + timeBetweenUpdates) {
                    callback(location);
                    time = new Date().getTime();
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                setLocationError(e);
            }
        }, []);
    
    
        useEffect(() => {
            let subscriber;
            const startWatching = async () => {
                try {
                    subscriber = await watchPositionAsync({
                            accuracy: Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
                            timeInterval: 10000,
                            distanceInterval: 0
                        }, innerLocationCallback
                    );
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log("Location Error: ", "caught error in catch block")
                    setLocationError(e);
                }
            };
    
            if (shouldTrackLocation && locationServicesOn && permissionGranted) {
                startWatching().catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    subscriber?.remove();
                    subscriber = null
                })
            } else {
                subscriber?.remove();
                subscriber = null;
            }
    
            return () => {
                subscriber?.remove();
            }
        }, [shouldTrackLocation, callback, locationServicesOn, permissionGranted]);
    
        return [locationError];
    }
```

I didn't want to make a major change on your code in advance since it is a little bit overcomplicated.
But personally i wouldn't call my outer callback like this. If this works for you, i can enhance my answer later.